# C# Base class with static list to be different between instantiated types?

Tags: c#, static-members

I have a need to create unique ID's for my objects which can be saved and loaded between application instances.

I have this working in my current implementation but it means each of my classes needs almost the same piece of code, therefore I decided to create a base class with this code in and then inherit from that. The code is below. The only issue I'm having is that because I have a *static list* in the base class, all inherited class types are getting added to the same list.

Therefore how can I change the code so that the List 'items' is a different list between types?

To clarify. If I have two classes list this:
Foo: UniqueObject
Bar: UniqueObject
I want to the Foo and Bar to have their own static **item** list

```cs
abstract class UniqueObject
{
    static protected List<UniqueObject> items = new List<UniqueObject>();
    static Random rnd = new Random();

    int id;

    public int Object_ID { get { return id; } }

    protected UniqueObject()
    {
        id = generateUniqueID();
        items.Add(this);
    }

    protected UniqueObject(int Object_ID)
    {
        // Ensure the passed ID is unique
        if (!isIdUnique(Object_ID))
        {
            // if not it does not get added to the items list and an exception is thrown.
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Object ID is not unique. Already being used by another object.");
        }

        // If we get here then must have been unique so add it.
        items.Add(this);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Generates the unique identifier.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The unique ID</returns>
    private int generateUniqueID()
    {
        // get a random number
        int val = rnd.Next();

        // check it is unique, if not get another and try again.
        while (!isIdUnique(val))
        {
            val = rnd.Next();
        }

        return val;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks that the passed ID is unique against the other
    /// objects in the 'items' list.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ID">The identifier.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private bool isIdUnique(int ID)
    {
        foreach (UniqueObject c in items)
        {
            if (c.id == ID)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I believe I can achieve this using Generics so i could change the class and list to something like this:

```cs
abstract class UniqueObject<T>
{
    static protected List<T> items = new List<T>();
```

But this gives other errors with the line items.Add(this).

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Why does the list have to be static?
If you have a static object it is created once when your program starts and there won't be multiple instances.

Comment: "I have a need to create unique ID's for my objects" - just use a GUID....(looks like an XY problem)

Comment: GUID or [Path.GetRandomFileName()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getrandomfilename(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Object ids must be unique for each type or per app domain? (for all types that inherit from your base UniqueObject class)

Comment: When does "GenerateUniqueId" is called ?

Comment: @ M4s0n - I created the list static so that the when a new object is created it can generate an ID and check that it is indeed unique against the others. But yes i agree there wont be multiple instances, which is what I am tring to work around.

Comment: You need to abstract the notion of unicity into a separate service that you can move around in whatever tier / layer of your application. Your objects must NOT contain logic about unicity, this notion is a separate concern and you must be deal with it in other component. Please apply the separation of concern pattern

Comment: I'll look into the GUID, I did already look into ObjectIDGenerator but I wasnt sure if you could assign ID's manually. This is needed as when the object is first created i need a generated ID of some sort. When the application is closed I use XML to save all objects and either ID's so they can be loaded again when the application is fired up next time. Hence the reason I have two constructors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your last remark about using generics, I guess you could do this:

```
abstract class UniqueObject<T> where T : class
```

And then

```
items.Add(this as T);
```

This should work, and `this as T` should never fail on runtime if you don't explicitly use `UniqueObject<>`.

I'm not sure about how I feel about advocating having static members on generic types ([and you should not do that](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182139.aspx)), but this should at least work

*Update*: yes, it [seems to work](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iBZb0s)

### Recommendation

In my answer, I tried to answer exactly what you were asking. But with all this said, if all you need is a unique ID for your objects and checking if it's not duplicated when you create them, you could:

1. Use a GUID, and forget about checking. GUID collisions are theoretically possible.... but will it happen? Under normal conditions, more likely not. Even if you created a trillion GUIDs in a year, there's a higher chance your program will crash by a meteorite striking the computer *several times* before you find a duplicate
2. Still, if you want to check it and make absolutely sure (which is a fair thing to do, actually), this could be way easier, and you don't need to store a list of the whole objects per-type to do this... see this simple base class, which will do what you want in a similar way you are doing it:

   ```
   abstract class UniqueObject : IDisposable
   {
      static protected HashSet<Guid> Guids = new HashSet<Guid>();
      Guid _id;

      public Guid ObjectID { get { return _id; } }

      protected UniqueObject()
      {
        do
        {
          _id = Guid.NewGuid();
        } while(Guids.Contains(_id));           
        Guids.Add(_id);
      }  

      protected UniqueObject(Guid guid)
      {
        if(Guids.Contains(guid))
          throw new ArgumentNullException("Object ID is not unique. Already being used by another object.");
        _id = guid;
      }

      // Make a better implementation of IDisposable
      public void Dispose()
      {
        guids.Remove(_id);
      }
   }
   ```

And that's it. If you still want to use `int` instead of `Guid`, you could just change it to `int`, and have something like:

```
// static members
static protected Random rnd = new Random();
static protected HashSet<int> ids = new HashSet<int>();
// ... in the constructor:
do
{
  _id = rnd.Next();
} while(ids.Contains(_id));
```

Which looks similar to what you had before

Comment: thanks for this it appears to work well with my current system with little changes :) I have one issue that it now breaks and wonder if you have a suggestion; My function above 'isIdUnique(int ID)' doesnt like the cast to UniqueObject which is needed to access the 'c.id'

Comment: This seems to have solved it 
        `private bool isIdUnique(int ID)
        {
            foreach (T c in items)
            {
                UniqueObject<T> cc = c as UniqueObject<T>;
                if (cc.id == ID)
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }`

Comment: @TheGrovesy you could do `foreach(var c in items.OfType<UniqueObject<T>>())`, then again, that whole method could be easily rewritten as simply: `return !items.OfType<UniqueObject<T>>().Any(x => x.id == ID);`. [Check it](https://dotnetfiddle.net/h8iI26)

Comment: Also, you could use the constraint: `where T : UniqueObject<T>`, and then you wouldn't need any casting. [Check it](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YeX9SX)

Comment: @TheGrovesy I actually felt "wrong" for advocating you to use a static member in a generic type, it's something that feels "wrong", so I wrote an updated answer, which may fit your scenario and not need many changes to your codeif you are using this kind of pattern

Comment: thanks for all this help, very much appricated, understood and useful. I think I'll tweek my code to use a few bits of yours. thanks again.

Comment: As a final tip, don't use `ArgumentNullException` (I just copied from yours), `ArgumentException` should be the correct exception here (it's what `Dictionary<>` throws when adding a duplicate key, for example :-) )

Answer (score 1):

If you want an unique id that has the folowing properties:

1) Is unique in current app domain

2) Values are unique even when dealing with multiple instances of your application.

Then you need to consider one of these solutions:

1) Generate GUIDS

2) Have a unique "server" for your generated ids (a common server that can serve your ids)

3) If you know exactly how many application instances you have, you can define a "series" of unique ids for each instance.

And last, you need to abstract the notion of unicity into a separate service that you can move around in whatever tier / layer of your application. Your objects must NOT contain logic about unicity, this notion is a separate concern and you must be deal with it in other component. Please apply the separation of concerns pattern.

So this is my implementation (if I would be you)

```
public interface IEntityWithUniqueId
{
    void SetUniqueId(string uniqueId);

    string UniqueId { get; }
}

public interface IUniqueIdsProvider
{
    string GetNewId();
}

public class UniqueObject : IEntityWithUniqueId
{
    public string UniqueId { get; private set; }

    void IEntityWithUniqueId.SetUniqueId(string uniqueId)
    {
        UniqueId = uniqueId;
    }
}

public class MyObjects : UniqueObject
{

}

public class RemoteUniqueIdsProvider : IUniqueIdsProvider
{
    public string GetNewId()
    {
        // calling a service ...., grab an unique ID
        return Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace ("-", "");
    }
}

public class UniqueObjectsFactory<T> where T : IEntityWithUniqueId, new ()
{
    private IUniqueIdsProvider _uniqueIdsProvider;
    public UniqueObjectsFactory(IUniqueIdsProvider uniqueIdsProvider)
    {
        _uniqueIdsProvider = uniqueIdsProvider;
    }

    public T GetNewEntity()
    {
        var x = new T();
        x.SetUniqueId(_uniqueIdsProvider.GetNewId ());

        return x;
    }
}
```

I wrote a test method like this:

```
[TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void UniqueObjectTest()
        {
            var provider = new RemoteUniqueIdsProvider();

            var factory = new UniqueObjectsFactory<MyObjects>(provider);

            var entity = factory.GetNewEntity();
            var entity2 = factory.GetNewEntity();

            Assert.AreNotEqual(entity.UniqueId, entity2.UniqueId);


        }

    }
```

To explain what is above:
1) The interface IEntityWithUniqueId defines how an "unique" object must look like in your application, so it is an object that has an UniqueId property and also a special method: SetUniqueId. I didn't made the property UniqueId with get and set because "set" would be an infrastructure operation but get will be a developer API.

2) The interface IUniqueIdsProvider tells you how a unique ids provider will look like. It must have a simple method: GetNewId (); that serves you an unique Id. The implementation can be anywhere (on a server, locally, etc)

3) UniqueObject class. This class is the base class for all your unique objects.

4) UniqueObjectsFactory. This is the class that serves you new unique objects. When loading objects from disk, you must start from the asumption that you GENERATED unique ids, so when loading them you don't have to deal with checking unicity again.

Comment: I guess the point of all of this would be having a list of created objects per type that self-manages. You can do this (having a `Dictionary`, for example) with your implementation, but I guess the point of having a static `List` per type was the most important part

Comment: Self management does not exclude the ideea of having an external service that serves you whatever unique id you need / want. Secondly, you would need the list ONLY and ONLY if you want to do something more, for example you want to be able to call something on all your  "unique" objects, so you would need another monster: an unique object manager, not the object himself.

Comment: Oh yes, I'm not saying I don't agree... personally, I'd just have a `Guid` on a base object and manage those lists (if needed) externally to the object. The whole OP's implementation looks pretty badly thought to me

Comment: Thanks for example and explaination George, very helpful. However I have a question:- One thing I did not mention, but seems relevent now, is that I need each instance to have access to the list of items of the same type. This is because each instance will have also have unique string names. And when the user changes the name (using the PropertyGrid) the instance needs to check that it is unique within the list. I think in your solution **MyObject** does not have access to the Factory does it?

Comment: @TheGrovesy For that you need a presenter object that handles this logic (unicity of names within a grid). For further details, you could read about MVP pattern or PM pattern (http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PresentationModel.html) so the main ideea is to separate the "unicity of names" logic that is a business rule from your actual entity (that it's just a bag of "Name" and "Id"). You could use whatever pattern you want, i gave you just an ideea to smell and find the best aproach.

Comment: @TheGrovesy So the factory is just a factory, it does not have to deal with logic such as "Name" must be unique within a certain situation. The factory single responsibility is to provide new objects with unique Id. Adding a new logic such as "if editing, Name must be unique" is not the factory concern ...